# Why does my simple Excel formula =SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1, A2:A5) return #VALUE error?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumproduct

I've got a horizontal range of numbers in cells, and a vertical range of numbers in some other cells. I want a product of those ranges. For example cells `A1:D1` contain 1,2,3,4 and cells `A2:A5` contain values 5, 6,7,8. I except to get an answer of 70.

I run `=SUMPRODUCT(A1:D1, A2:A5)` and it gives me `#VALUE`. Same problem for other simple examples like this. I have no idea why. According to all my sources I've read (including ChatGPT) this formula should work?

Tried various cell range lengths and values, in different positions, but same problem.

Comment: You are not getting the desired output because they are not corresponding to each other even though they have same dimensions, to get the desired output, you need to do the following: `=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D1),A2:A5)` or `SUM(TOCOL(A1:D1)*A2:A5)`

Comment: Thanks. Is there any more direct formula to calculate a product of numbers in a row and a column in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

The formula in the OP is not working because as per `MSFT` Documentations, `SUMPRODUCT()` function returns the product of corresponding ranges or arrays, where the default operation is multiplication. However, one can use addition, subtraction or division as well, which is possible. Read **[here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/sumproduct-function-16753e75-9f68-4874-94ac-4d2145a2fd2e)**.

---

Now, the question is even though the data has same dimensions and same sizes its still not working because its not corresponding to each other in order to return the desired output `70`. Two options, transpose one of the ranges so it becomes corresponding to one another and then apply the function.

---

• Using `SUMPRODUCT()` with `TRANSPOSE()` function:

[image]

---

```
=SUMPRODUCT(TRANSPOSE(A1:D1),A2:A5)
```

---

Or, Using `SUM()` with `TOCOL()`

```
=SUM(A2:A5*TOCOL(A1:D1))
```

---

Comment: Thanks, so turns out ChatGPT does not answer a simple question correctly...@Mayukh

Comment: @Astral could be I am not sure. Not really tried yet.

Comment: @Astral You are better off looking in the Excel help compared to ChatGPT... Nobody has posted on here saying "I have an excellent answer from ChatGPT":...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MMULT function...

```
=MMULT(A1:D1,A2:A5)
```

Note, though, the formula will return #VALUE! if one or more cells are empty/blank.